# Deleted almost everything. Recovery methods?

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, recovery-mode

I deleted almost everything on the system except chromium and pdf I guess. No software centre no apt-get. I mean there is nothing. Is there anyway I can restore all the bundled software etc with 12.04?

Comment: How did that happen? In order to help you we'll have to trace your steps back.

Comment: I would assume you didn't delete them from the trash?

Comment: What steps did you perform to delete said software?

Answer (score 3):

***Simplest Method.***

- Make sure any user data (documents, images, etc.) or critical settings are **Backed-Up**.
- Decide what, if anything, needs to be retained.
- Re-install **Ubuntu**.

***Repeat as needed, until you stop having those (pesky)*** 'Deleted almost everything.' ***impulses ..***